# How to add Core Data to my project and store the data getting from JSON service

Tags: ios, iphone, json, core-data, ios7

i am doing in appDelegate.h like this

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
```

and implementinig all these things in appDelegate.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty big question to handle, but typically you'd add something like this (if you're using UIManagedDocument) to your appdelegate.m's `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *documentsDirectory = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                 inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
NSString *documentName = @"YOUR_DATABASE_NAME";
NSURL *url = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:documentName];
self.document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[url path]];
if (fileExists) {
    [self.document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            self.context = self.document.managedObjectContext;
            // Post notification so others can gather the document and context
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DatabaseReady"
                                                                object:self];
        }
        if (!success) NSLog(@"couldn't open file at %@", url);
    }];
} else {
    [self.document saveToURL:url
            forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
           completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
               if (success) {
                   self.context = self.document.managedObjectContext;
                   // Post notification so others can gather the document and context
                   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DatabaseReady"
                                                                       object:self];
               }
               if (!success) NSLog(@"couldn't open file at %@", url);
           }];
}
```

You should put `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIManagedDocument *document;` in your appdelegate's .h file so that other view controllers can get the document. In view controllers that need to contact the database in some way, add this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Listen for UIManagedDocument so that we can get the database set up right
    // This only works in awakeFromNib (viewDidLoad is too late)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(getUIManagedDocument:)
                                                 name:@"DatabaseReady"
                                               object:nil];
}
```

Then, you'll need to add the `getUIManagedDocument:` method to your view controller:

```
- (void)getUIManagedDocument:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.document = [(OneWorldAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] document];
    self.context = self.document.managedObjectContext;
}
```

Of course you'll need to add

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIManagedDocument *document;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *context;
```

to your files. That's where `self.context` comes from.

At that point, you are ready to start doing things with your database.

**IMPORTANT:** Don't forget to `#import` your appdelegate's .h file in the view controller in which you'd like to access the appdelegate's @property `document`!

As far as getting JSON data, I recommend that you work through a tutorial, like [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial). It explains things quite clearly.

Hope it helps!

Comment: What is  self.context

Comment: It's the NSManagedObjectContext public @property that both the appdelegate and the view controller that wants to access the database have. All interaction with Core Data occurs within that context. In your original post, you used `@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;` instead of my `context`, but it's the same idea. Doesn't matter what you call it.

Comment: i done all this but how to get the data from JSON to database

Comment: That's why I included the tutorial; it's a substantial task. Work through the tutorial, focusing mostly on the section "The NSURLSession suite of classes" and later. If you have questions about something within it, you can ask on stackoverflow.